# I have a warning when using vite dev: "files in the public directory are served at the root path."

Tags: vuejs3

When I use vite dev, I am prompted that “files in the public directory are served at the root path.Instead of /public/fonts/iconfont.woff2, use /fonts/woff2”, but my path does use/fonts/woff2

I want to know how to get rid of this warning